# Input does not focus on cursor when cursor position is set

Tags: javascript, html, dom, cursor-position

I'm working with an HTML input of type `text`. I'm manually getting and setting the cursor of the input programmatically in JS using the [Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection).

When the cursor is set to a particular position like this, the scroll for the input isn't automatically focused on the cursor's location. To force the scroll to focus, the input's `scrollLeft` has to be manually calculated and set where the cursor's location would be. This is where the problem arises.

The cursor's position is set by the index of the character in the input's string of text. If there are 40 characters in the string, setting the cursor to position 40 would set it to the end of the string. Unfortunately, `scrollLeft` is set using the width of each character, in pixels. Since all character's aren't the same width this presents a problem. This means, to manually set the focus of the input element to the position of the cursor, you must calculate the width of each character between the start of the string and the cursor's position index.

The easiest way I've thought of to accomplish this is to create a second input that's used to measure the width of each character in the string individually. Since theres no way to automatically get the width of any given character, the `scrollWidth` of this second input would equal the width of that single character. For my use case, the cursor will only ever change position one index at a time. This means I can increment or decrement the `scrollLeft` the width of each character one at a time.

Because this is would be super complicated, I'm wondering if anyone has come across something simple that will accomplish my goal. Something like:

```
inputEL.scrollLeft = 'auto';
```

Note: Manually setting the cursor in the input and then calling `focus()` on that input doesn't work. But something like that would be ideal.